# $\ker\phi$ closed implies $\phi$ bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space and $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a nonzero linear functional. If $\ker\phi$ is closed then $\phi$ is bounded.

I have some trouble to understand the solution given by the assistant:

**Solution:**

We have $X/\ker \phi$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So the map $\tilde{\phi}:X/\ker \phi\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map between finit-dimensional vector spaces. $\tilde{\phi}$ is bounded. So $\phi:\tilde{\phi}\circ\pi$ is bounded, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection.

Why is $X/\ker \phi$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: Oh thank you @ZackNi I didn't know this

Comment: Hint: If $\phi(x) \ne 0$, then $\phi\left(y-\frac{\phi(y)}{\phi(x)}x\right)=0$, which gives $y = \frac{\phi(y)}{\phi(x)}x+\left[y-\frac{\phi(y)}{\phi(x)}x\right]$.

Comment: This question was shown among related questions in the sidebar: [$T$ is continuous if and only if $\ker T$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131842).