# If the kernel of a seminorm $p$ is closed, is $p$ then continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional normed $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.
Let $p:V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a seminorm on $V$, and let $K=\ker p= \{ v \in V : p(v)=0\}$ be its kernel.

I would like to know if
$$K\text{ is closed }\Longrightarrow\:p\text{ is continuous}$$
is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$T$ is continuous if and only if $\ker T$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131842/t-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-ker-t-is-closed)

Comment: Which topology is $p$ supposed to be continuous with respect to?

Comment: @Javi a seminorm is not a linear functional so my question isn't duplicate

Comment: @TheoBendit $p$ is continuous as map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MateyMath A vector space $V$, without some kind of topology/norm doesn't have a topology by default. So, saying $p$ is continuous as a map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't work without extra information, as continuous maps only exist between topological spaces. What is the topology on $V$? Is it induced by $p$ (in which case $p$ is necessarily continuous)? Is it the discrete topology? The indiscrete topology? Is there another norm?

Comment: @TheoBendit ok thanks, now i understand your question, the topology on $V$ is induced by norm ($V$ is a normed space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no", even if you strengthen the question to norms, rather than seminorms. Note that each norm necessarily has a trivial kernel, which is always closed under the norm on $V$, but due to the fact that norms need not be equivalent in infinite dimensions, this implies that norms will not necessarily be continuous with respect to each other.

Comment: thanks for your answer