# Close $M=\{\:x(t)\in{L_2}_{[1,\infty)}:\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt=0\:\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

> Show that $M$ is closed in ${L_2}_{[1,\infty)}$
>
> $$M=\left\{\:x(t)\in{L_2}_{[1,\infty)}:\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt=0\:\right\}$$

I thought of using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem to prove $M$ is compact then conclude it is closed.
However I have no idea on how to address equicountinuity in a set like $M$. To prove the function is equincontinuous:

$$\delta>0\:,\:\epsilon>0,\qquad|t-t_0|<\delta\implies\|x(t)-X(t_0)\|_{{L_2}_{[1,\infty)}}<\epsilon\:\:\:\forall x(t)\in M$$

**Question:**

**1)** How should I prove equicountinuity on this case?

**2)** Are there alternative methods? What are those?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am maybe mistaken but it seems to me that Arzela-Ascoli only gives relative compacity and in particular does not say that $M$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $L^{2}[1,\infty)$ which $x_{n}\in M$, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)}{t}dt\right|&=\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)-x_{n}(t)}{t}dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_{n}(t)}{t}dt\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)-x_{n}(t)}{t}dt\right|\\
&\leq\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{t^{2}}dt\right)^{1/2}\|x_{n}-x\|_{L^{2}[1,\infty)}\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: So you prove that $x_n\to x$ defines a convergent sequence in $M$, therefore  $M$ is a complete subspace of complete linear space hence it is closed. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, you can view it like that in this case. By the way, there is a sequential characterization of closedness in normed space.

Answer (score 3):

Let:
$$\phi:L^2 \to \Bbb R, f \mapsto \int_1^\infty \frac{f(t)}{t}$$
then $\phi$ is a linear form and $M=\ker(\phi)$, so the closure of $M$ is equivalent to the continuity of $\phi$.

And by Cauchy-Swchartz:
$$|\phi(f)| \leq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t} |f(t)| dt \leq \sqrt{ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} dt}\sqrt{ \int_1^\infty |f(t)|^2 dt}=1 \times \|f\|_{L^2}$$
so $\phi$ is continuous.

(In fact $\phi(f)=\left\langle t \mapsto \frac{1}{t} , f \right\rangle$ and $t \mapsto \frac{1}{t} \in L^2([1,+\infty))$)

Comment: Please explain me how the closure is related to the continuity. I am missing that point.

Comment: A linear form is continuous iff its kernel is closed (see  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131842/t-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-ker-t-is-closed) ).

Here you need only the "easy" direction: if $\phi$ is continuous then:
$$\phi^{-1} ( \{0 \} )$$
is closed as the inverse of a closed set ($\{0 \}$) by a continuous function ($\phi$).

Comment: Are you aware that the spaces are infinite dimensional?

Comment: Yes, but it does not change the fact that the inverse of a closed set by a continuous function is a closed set or the fact that a linear $\phi$ form is continuous iff $|\phi(f)| \leq C \| f\|$.

Answer (score 1):

$f \in L^2[1,\infty) \mapsto \langle f,1/t\rangle_{L^2[1,\infty)}$ is a continuous function, and you're looking at the inverse image of the closed scalar set $\{ 0\}$ under this continuous linear functional. So, this inverse image is closed, and that's your set $M$.