# relation between linear functional and kernel on nls

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a linear functional on a normed linear space $X$. Prove that $f$ is discontinious  iff   $ker(f)$ is a proper dense subspace of $X$
\ 
 I tried to get with discontinuity of $f$ but not getting the idea how to deal with kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is discontinuous. Then $f\neq 0$, so $\ker f$ is proper. To prove that $\ker f$ is dense in $X$, let $x_0\in X$, let $\lambda:=f(x_0)$, and let $\left\{y_n\right\}\subset X$ be a sequence such that $\|y_n\|=1$ and $|f(y_n)|\to +\infty $ (it exists because $f$ is discontinuous).
Now consider
$$x_n:=x_0-\frac{y_n}{f(y_n)}\lambda $$
then $f(x_n)=0$, so that $x_n\in \ker f$ for all $n$, and
$$\|x_n-x_0\|=\left|\frac{\lambda}{f(y_n)}\right|\to 0 $$
Therefore, $x_n\to x_0$, and $x_0\in \overline{\ker f}$.

Conversely, if $\ker f$ is proper and dense, it is non-closed, so since $\ker f$ is the preimage of the singleton $\left\{0\right\}$ (which is closed in $\mathbb{R}$), $f$ has to be discontinuous.

By the way, this is basically equivalent to the fact that [a linear functional is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131842/t-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-ker-t-is-closed)

Comment: But this not true if we have any linear transformation ,Just take $X=C^{1}[a,b] and Y =C[a,b]$ and $T(f)=f'$ then its kernel is closed but still T is not continuous.

Comment: Indeed. It only holds if the codomain is finite dimensional.