# Prove $\mathcal M_n$ is closed subspace of $\ell^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I've been solving problems from my Functional Analysis course and don't know how to approach this one:

> Given $\ell^2=\left\{\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb C :
>  \sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2<\infty\right\}$, $N\in\mathbb N$ and
> $$\mathcal M_N=\left\{\{a_n\}\subset \ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^N
>  a_n=0\right\},\phantom{aa} \mathcal K=\left\{\{a_n\}\subset
>  \ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0\right\}.$$ Prove $\mathcal M_N$
> is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$. Is $\mathcal K$ also closed?

I considered defining the linear mappings $T_N:\ell^2\to \mathbb C$ defined as
$$T_N(\{a_n\})=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n.$$
If I managed to prove it's continuous it would be done for $\mathcal M_N$. To prove it I think I must use the equivalence between continuity and boundedness for linear mappings between normed spaces. Minkowski's inequality gives me that
$$\left\| \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right\|\leq\sum_{n=1}^N\| a_n \|,$$
but I'm not sure how can I relate this to the hypothesis that the sum of the squares of the $a_n$ is finite (and how to use that to conclude each $T_N$ is bounded). For $\mathcal K$, I got no clue where to start.

How can I solve this? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is an error in defining $\mathcal{M}_n$ this way. The condition that the finite sum is convergent seems trivially true. Did you mean for the finite sum to equal $0$?

Comment: @TheoBendit You're right i'm sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Can you find a Cauchy sequence in $K$ which does not converge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}a_n|\leq \sqrt N \sqrt {\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}|a_n|^{2}}$ by Cauchy_Schwarz inequality. This proves that $T$ is continuous (with $\|T\| \leq \sqrt N$) and hence $\mathcal M_N$ is closed.
$\mathcal K$ is not closed. In fact, it is dense. In fact the kernel of any dis-continuous linear functional is dense. See [relation between linear functional and kernel on nls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857814/relation-between-linear-functional-and-kernel-on-nls/2857824#2857824)

[If $(a_n) \to \sum a_n$ is continuous then there exists a constant $C$ such that $|\sum a_n | \leq C \sqrt {\sum |a_n|^{2}}$ for all $(a_n) \in \ell^{2}$. Look at $(1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 3,...)$ to get a  contradiction].

Comment: The claim that $(a_n) \in \ell_2$ implies that $(a_1, \dots a_n, 0, 0, \dots) $ belongs to $K$  is not true.

Comment: @DionelJaime I have edited my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I understood your solution very well, thanks for your help! Now I'm trying to find the ortogonal space of each $\mathcal M_N^\perp$. I got $$\mathcal M_N^\perp=\left[ \{1,1,...,1,0,0,...\} \right]$$ (the $N$ first terms are $1$ and the rest are all $0$). I hope it's correct, tough my reasoning to reach that result may not be completely rigurous.

Comment: It is correct. @AlejandroBergasaAlonso