# Counter example to show that if $\ker(T)$ is closed and $W$ is not finite dimensional $T$ is not bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let operator $T:(V,\|-\|_v)\rightarrow(W,\|-\|_w)$.

I know that if $\ker(T)$ is closed and $W$ is finite dimensional, then $T$ is bounded. But is there an easy counter example to show that the finite-dimensional criterion is critical?

I know in the proof of the continuity of $T$ the finite dimensional property of $W$ is used to show that the quotient space of $V$ is finite-dim as well and the proof proceeds. But I can't derive a counter example from there.

Link to the proof of continuity :[$T$ is continuous if and only if $\ker T$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131842/t-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-ker-t-is-closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $V$ be the space of sequences with finitely many non zero terms with $Sup$ norm and the endomorphism of $V$ defined by $T(e_n)=ne_n$.

Comment: By $l^2$ do you mean $\ell _2$

Comment: What is the codomain of your map? How do you extend your map to all $l^2$