# If $f : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ is differentiable at a point $c \in \mathbb R^{n}$ then it is continuous there.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**My attempt** :

Let $f : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ be differentiable at $x = c \in \mathbb R^{n}$.Then there exists a linear operator $T_{c} : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ such that

$f(c + h) - f(c) = T_{c} (h) + ||h|| E_{c} (h)$ , where $E_{c} (h) \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.So taking limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ on both sides of the above equation we obtain

$$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} [f(c + h) - f(c)] = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} T_{c} (h)$$.

If we can show that $T_{c}$ is continuous at $0$ then our purpose will be served.

But I find difficulty to show this.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am sure that this question has been asked several times here on MSE,please do a google search before posting questions!

Comment: @ArpitKansal I don't find any such which met my purpose.

Comment: Since $\|T_c h \| \le \|T_c\| \|h \|$, it follows that $\lim_{h \to 0} T_c h = 0$.

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64680/a-linear-operator-on-a-finite-dimensional-hilbert-space-is-continuous).

Comment: All linear operators on finite dimensional normed spaces are continuous.

Comment: Yeh I got it.Thanks to copper.hat and G.Sassatelli.